# jQuery - Calling function that is defined within an anonymous function

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I did some extensive searching, but could not find an explicit answer to this.

I have two files, one I control, and the other I do not. Both start with the document ready anonymous function `jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {`, and both are included in my document.

The file I do not control, which is part of a framework, has a function defined within it named `adjust()`. Is there a chance I would be able to call that function `adjust()` from my file (or anywhere else besides the file I do not control)?

Comment: It depends, is `adjust` a global function?

Comment: Can you give us some more information? What is the "file [you] do not control?" Is it a public library? If so, which one?

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, it was a pretty generic question. @jfriend00 was able to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function scopes are private.  You cannot access functions defined within another function unless that other function "exports" that function in some way (returns it, assigns it to some publicly scoped object, etc...).